# CSS Text Outline not working in IE10 compatibility view

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

I use the following code to create text outline. The code works fine to create text outline in IE8 and IE10, however, when I enable compatibility view in IE10, I no longer see the text outline. Any ideas on why it doesn't work in IE10-Compatibility view and suggestions to debug this problem.

```
<span style="color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000000,  
    1px -1px 0 #000000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000000,
    1px 1px 0 #000000;
    filter: 
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100) 
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#000000,offX=1,offY=1) 
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#000000,offX=-1,offY=1) 
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#000000,offX=1,offY=-1) 
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#000000,offX=-1,offY=-1)\9;
    zoom: 1\9;">Hello</span>
```

Comment: If you open the dev tools (f12) what document mode does it show ?

Comment: @grimmus In IE10, document mode is "Quirks", and IE10 with Compatibility View, document mode is "IE5 quirks"

Answer (score 0):

```
//for outline css

<span style="color: white;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000000,  
1px -1px 0 #000000,
-1px 1px 0 #000000,
1px 1px 0 #000000;
filter: 
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100) 
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#000000,offX=1,offY=1) 
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#000000,offX=-1,offY=1) 
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#000000,offX=1,offY=-1) 
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#000000,offX=-1,offY=-1)\9;
zoom: 1\9;outline-width:1px;outline-style:solid;outline-color:red;">Hello</span>
```

Comment: maybe you could add some explanation to your answer, specifically how it resolves the problem. The idea is to teach.

Comment: no, this creates a rectangular border around the text, not a text outline